# update variable depending on form values

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's a pretty detailed form with many values to enter & the result is a price, the function to get the price depending on the main 2 select box is working fine it gives me a variable "price" that is updated on checkbox changes & select box changes, the problem is some check boxes affect the final price like add 40% of the total price the changes work perfectly fine with only 1 checkbox affecting the price but upon adding other inputs affecting the price it doesn't count in the previous inputs in.

I tried putting many conditions like if first check box is checked & first radio is selected do this : .. else if first check box is checked & second radio is selected do that : .. 
but it sounds complicated, I hope there is an easier way of doing it using j query or JavaScript

```js
function getPrice() {
//let's assume the price is 80
price = 80;
//order duo is supposed to add 20% of total price
if ($('#order_duo').is(':checked')) {
 document.getElementById("price").textContent=price + price*0.2;
 document.getElementById("price_input").value = price +  price*0.2;
}   
else {
    document.getElementById("price").textContent=price;
    document.getElementById("price_input").value = price;
}
//if prefered lane is support add 50% of total price
$('#prefered_lane').on('change', function() {
    prefered_lane = this.value;
    if (prefered_lane === "Support") {
      getPrice();
      price =   parseInt(document.getElementById("price_input").value);
    document.getElementById("price").textContent=price + price*0.5;
    document.getElementById("price_input").value = price +  price*0.5;
  }else{
    getPrice();
    price = document.getElementById("price_input").value;
     document.getElementById("price").textContent=price;
    document.getElementById("price_input").value = price;
  }
}); 
}
$('#prefered_lane').on('change', function() {
  getPrice();
  });
$('#order_duo').click(
    function () {
     if ($('#order_duo').is(':checked')) {
   getPrice();
}   
else {
    getPrice();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <input type="text" name="price_input" id="price_input" value="" hidden="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="order_duo" class="form-check-input" id="order_duo"  style="width: 20px;height: 20px;">
<select id="prefered_lane" name="prefered_lane" class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;"  autocomplete="off">
  <option value="Top Lane">Top Lane</option>
  <option value="Jungle">Jungle</option>
  <option value="Mid Lane">Mid Lane</option>
  <option value="AD Carry">AD Carry</option>
  <option value="Support">Support (+50%)</option>
</select>  

<div class="first">Buy Now</div>
<div class="second">For € <strong id="price"></strong></div>
                    
</form>
```

Once you uncheck duo while selecting support price resets to 80 :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting your price in each calculation in the `getPrice` function, but you are not taking into account both `lane` and `duo` conditions, only `duo`.

The `$('#prefered_lane').on()` block inside the function doesn't execute during your price calculation. What it does is add a *new* event handler to the `select` element, so the result is that if you uncheck `duo`, price goes back to the original 80.

Having this in mind, you can clean up your code:

```js
// Do calculations whenever any element changes
$('#order_duo, #prefered_lane').change(function() {
  //let's assume the price is 80
  let price = 80;

  //order duo is supposed to add 20% of total price
  if ($('#order_duo').is(':checked')) {
    price = price * 1.2;
  }
  //if prefered lane is support add 50% of total price
  if ($('#prefered_lane').val() === "Support") {
    price = price * 1.5;
  }

  $('#price').text(price);
  $('#price_input').val(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="price_input" id="price_input" value="" hidden="">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="order_duo" class="form-check-input" id="order_duo" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;">
  <select id="prefered_lane" name="prefered_lane" class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="Top Lane">Top Lane</option>
    <option value="Jungle">Jungle</option>
    <option value="Mid Lane">Mid Lane</option>
    <option value="AD Carry">AD Carry</option>
    <option value="Support">Support (+50%)</option>
  </select>

  <div class="first">Buy Now</div>
  <div class="second">For € <strong id="price"></strong></div>

</form>
```